# How do I make fonts of different sizes vertically centered in html spans?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm making a pitch controller:

```
<div id="pitchWrapper">
  <span id="pitchButtons">-</span>
  <span id="pitchValue">0</span>
  <span id="pitchButtons">+</span>
</div>
```

I want the minus, plus, and pitch value all to be vertically centered. I want the plus and minus to be a bigger font-size than the pitch value.

It works reasonably well when I set the font sizes to all be the same...

[image]

...but when I try to make the pitch buttons bigger, they align below center:

[image]

Here's my css:

```
#pitchWrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#pitchValue {
  font-size: 200%;
}

#pitchButtons {
  font-size: 300%;
}
```

How can I increase the font size of the pitch buttons while keeping everything vertically centered please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your CSS instead of vertical-align, try `justify-content: center`

Answer (score 1):

first, you cannot use the id selector and Select Plus and minus together. id must be unique. And why not use the Font awesome icon?

```css
#pitchWrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.pitchValue {
  font-size: 200%;
}

.pitchButtons {
  font-size: 300%;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/dc0c634418.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div id="pitchWrapper">
  <span class="pitchButtons">
      <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
    </span>
  <span class="pitchValue">0</span>
  <span class="pitchButtons">
      <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `align-items: baseline;`.

```css
#pitchWrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
}
#pitchValue {
    font-size: 200%;
}
.pitchButtons {
    font-size: 300%;
}
```

```html
<div id="pitchWrapper">
  <span class="pitchButtons">-</span>
  <span id="pitchValue">0</span>
  <span class="pitchButtons">+</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Hex code](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/math/) for Math Symbols.

```css
#pitchWrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#pitchValue {
  font-size: 150%;
}

.pitchButtons {
  font-size: 300%;
}
```

```html
<div id="pitchWrapper">
  <span class="pitchButtons">&#8722;</span>
  <span id="pitchValue">0</span>
  <span class="pitchButtons">&#x2B;</span>
</div>
```